# Как перемешать коллекции?

Tags: java, коллекции, случайные-числа

У меня есть два вопроса

1. Как перемешать эту коллекцию? Если нельзя, то какую другую использовать? Главное, чтобы каждое число было уникально.
2. Как обратиться к нулевому элементу этой коллекции?

Мой вывод всегда такой:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

```java
HashSet<Integer> usedQuestions = new HashSet<>();
Iterator<Integer> iterator = usedQuestions.iterator();
while (true) {
    int РАНДОМЧИСЛО = (int) (Math.random() * МАССИВ.length);
    usedQuestions.add(РАНДОМЧИСЛО);
    System.out.println(usedQuestions);
    if (usedQuestions.size() >= МАССИВ.length) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вашего примера это `HashSet` который не хранит порядок вставки. Заменив на `LinkedHashSet` вы получите желаемое:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HashSet<Integer> usedQuestions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    while (true) {
        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 8);
        usedQuestions.add(randomNumber);
        System.out.println(usedQuestions);
        if (usedQuestions.size() >= 8) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(usedQuestions);
    System.out.println(usedQuestions.toArray()[0]); // Первый элемент.
    // Конечно, правильно проверять массив перед обращением к элементам
    // по индексу, но в данном случае я знаю, что он там есть.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Пример:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1. Текст1");
list.add("2. Текст2. продолжение текста");
list.add("3. Текст3. еще текст. и еще текст");

Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: не успел слить :(

Comment: @AzizUmarov, такое бывает :)

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования побочных эффектов от многопоточности:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8};

Arrays.stream(arr).parallel()
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + " ")); // 8 1 4 5 2 6 
Arrays.stream(arr).parallel()
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + " ")); // 5 8 4 2 6 1 

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

Вывод будет всегда разным, при этом сам массив останется прежним.

Comment: Конечно это замечательно. Но как эти пользоваться?